# How can I invalidate AWS CloudFront Distribution cache using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws

I am looking for a way to invalidate the CloudFront distribution cache using Terraform.

I could not find any information in the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudfront_distribution).

Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: You could maybe run a `local-exec` provisioner to do that, but it's something off the top of my mind.

Comment: local-exec  to run a aws cli command?

Comment: Well, yes, I can't think of anything else if you want to do it with Terraform. I have done the cache invalidation in one of the CI/CD steps also using the AWS CLI command. Maybe you'll get a better answer than this. :) I would like to know if someone has done it differently. :)

Comment: Are we planning to invalidate all the files in the cache at every TF run? Not sure what origin are we using however assuming/If your origin is S3 bucket, you could setup something automated with the help of S3 Event Notification and Lambda so that whenever the file is changed a lambda is triggered to invalidate the same file. More info - https://medium.com/@yagonobre/automatically-invalidate-cloudfront-cache-for-site-hosted-on-s3-3c7818099868
Otherwise, local-exec as pointed out by Marko is an option.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**There is no in-built support within the [`aws_cloudfront_distribution`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudfront_distribution) or [`aws_cloudfront_cache_policy`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudfront_cache_policy) resource for cache invalidation.**

**As a last resort, the `local_exec` provisioner can be used.**

---

Typically, from my experience, the cache is invalidated within the CI/CD pipeline using the AWS CLI [`create-invalidation`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudfront/create-invalidation.html) command.

However, if this must be done within Terraform,  you can use the `local-exec` provisioner to run commands on the local machine running Terraform after the resource has been created/updated.

We can use this to run the above CLI invalidation command to invalidate the distribution cache.

Use the `self` object to access all of the CloudFront distribution's attributes, including [`self.id`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/cloudfront_distribution#id) to reference the CloudFront distribution ID for the invalidation

---

Example:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "s3_distribution" {
  # ...

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id ${self.id} --paths '...'"
  }
}
```