# Invalidate cloudfront cache of local files uploaded to s3 using Terraform

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws

I originally intended to post an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69794727/how-can-i-invalidate-aws-cloudfront-distribution-cache-using-terraform), however it seemed off-topic as I had a specific use-case around invalidating local files which are uploaded to s3.

I want local files which are uploaded to an s3 bucket, and served via cloudfront, to be invalidated when changed.

My solution isn't perfect; I have detailed some caveats.
It does however satisfy what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
resource null_resource cache_invalidation {
  # prevent invalidating cache before new s3 file is uploaded
  depends_on = [
    aws_s3_object.html_files,
    aws_s3_object.css_files,
  ]

  for_each = fileset("${path.module}/<LOCAL_FILES_TO_S3_TO_CLOUDFRONT>/", "**")

  triggers = {
    hash = filemd5("<LOCAL_FILES_TO_S3_TO_CLOUDFRONT>/${each.value}")
  }

  provisioner local-exec {
    # sleep is necessary to prevent throttling when invalidating many files; a dynamic sleep time would be more reliable
    # possible way of dealing with parallelism (though would lose the indiviual triggers): https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/specify-parallelism-for-null-resource/20884/2
    command = "sleep 1; aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id ${aws_cloudfront_distribution.this.id} --paths '/${each.value}'"
  }
}
```

*Caveat 1: the first time this is run it will want to invalidate all listed files.*

*Caveat 2: if dozens, or more, files are to be invalidated it's likely that you will get throttling errors from AWS. This will just require a few initial runs of `apply`.*

---

If like me you have certain files under `<LOCAL_FILES_TO_S3_TO_CLOUDFRONT>` that you don't wanted invalidated (for me I didn't need this for the `img/` subfolder) you can use [`setintersection`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/setintersection) to filter out these files whilst maintaining the proper paths for use in `triggers`:

```
resource null_resource cache_invalidation {
  # prevent invalidating cache before new s3 file is uploaded
  depends_on = [
    aws_s3_object.html_files,
    aws_s3_object.css_files,
  ]

  for_each = setsubtract(
    fileset("${path.module}/<LOCAL_FILES_TO_S3_TO_CLOUDFRONT>/", "**"),
    [for file in fileset("${path.module}/<LOCAL_FILES_TO_S3_TO_CLOUDFRONT>/img/", "*") : "img/${file}"],
  )

  triggers = {
    hash = filemd5("<LOCAL_FILES_TO_S3_TO_CLOUDFRONT>/${each.value}")
  }

  provisioner local-exec {
    # sleep is necessary to prevent throttling when invalidating many files
    # possible way of dealing with parallelism (though would lose the indiviual triggers): https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/specify-parallelism-for-null-resource/20884/2
    command = "sleep 1; aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id ${aws_cloudfront_distribution.this.id} --paths '/${each.value}'"
  }
}
```